# Rows to Columns - Oracle - Not using Union ALL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any better way achieve the below result other than using union all?
The table has millions of records, so looking for a better option where the result set is fetched once.

```
create table test_tab (
  rec_id number(3),
  p_code varchar2(5),
  q_code varchar2(5),
  r_code varchar2(5),
  p_amt number(8),
  q_amt number(8),
  r_amt number(8)
);

delete from test_tab;
insert into test_tab (rec_id, p_code, q_code,r_code , p_amt,q_amt,r_amt)
            values (1, 'p1','q1','r1',18,9,9);
insert into test_tab (rec_id, p_code, q_code,r_code , p_amt,q_amt,r_amt)
            values (2, 'p2','q2','r2',28,6,4);
insert into test_tab (rec_id, p_code, q_code,r_code , p_amt,q_amt,r_amt)
            values (3, 'p1',null,null,18,null,null);
insert into test_tab (rec_id, p_code, q_code,r_code , p_amt,q_amt,r_amt)
            values (4, null,'q3','r3',null,9,9);
commit;

select rec_id, p_code,p_amt from test_tab where p_code is not null
union all 
select rec_id, q_code,q_amt from test_tab where q_code is not null
union all 
select rec_id, r_code,r_amt from test_tab where r_code is not null;
```

Result:

| REC_ID | P_CODE | P_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | q1 | 9 |
| 1 | p1 | 18 |
| 1 | r1 | 9 |
| 2 | p2 | 28 |
| 2 | q2 | 6 |
| 2 | r2 | 4 |
| 3 | p1 | 18 |
| 4 | q3 | 9 |
| 4 | r3 | 9 |

Comment: Thank you for providing test data in the best possible format - even long-term members of this community rarely do that. Best thing you can do, so we can help you, is to do exactly what you did: help us, for example by providing usable test data. +1 even for that alone.

Comment: Note about this site: don't use `<code> ... </code>` tags; to mark code here, select the code, and either press Ctrl-K or select the `{}` icon from the formatting toolbar. I fixed it for you in this thread, but keep that in mind for the future. If you look at the post in "editing" view, you will see that all this does is to indent the lines by 4 spaces (and, indeed, **anything** you indent by four or more spaces **will** be formatted as code, whether you want it to be or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic application of the `unpivot` operator, available since Oracle 11.1.

```
select   rec_id, code, amt
from     test_tab
unpivot  ((code, amt) for ord in 
               ((p_code, p_amt) as 1, (q_code, q_amt) as 2, (r_code, r_amt) as 3))
order by rec_id, ord   --  if needed
;


    REC_ID CODE         AMT
---------- ----- ----------
         1 p1            18
         1 q1             9
         1 r1             9
         2 p2            28
         2 q2             6
         2 r2             4
         3 p1            18
         4 q3             9
         4 r3             9

9 rows selected.
```

Notice a few things. I call the output columns `code` and `amt` - it makes no sense to have the prefix `p_` in the output column names. Also, "exclude nulls" is the default in `unpivot`, so I didn't need to mention it explicitly (although it wouldn't hurt anything). Finally, while perhaps not critical, I also created a column `ord` to reflect column order, and ordered the rows in the output in the same order as you had the columns in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select x.*
from test_tab t cross join lateral
     (select t.rec_id, t.p_code as code, t.p_amount as amount from dual union all
      select t.rec_id, t.q_code, t.q_amount from dual union all
      select t.rec_id, t.r_code, t.r_amount from dual
     ) x
where code is not null;
```

Technical, this still has a `union all`, but it is only scanning the original table once.

Comment: The OP provided test data. It would be very easy to test your query - to find out that it doesn't work. (I just did, so I know.) A few obvious mistakes - you select `v.*` but there is no `v` anywhere; in the `lateral` clause, you select `t.something` from dual, which won't work, etc. I will remove the downvote if you can fix the code so that it is valid. Otherwise feel free to just delete the answer.

Comment: You still didn't **test** your query though, did you? The OP provided perfectly fine testing data, in usable format (create table and insert). Why not use it? There is still one issue in your query that causes it to fail; I will let you find it and fix it. (If you can't test on your own system, you can use something like livesql or sqlfiddle; no excuse for not testing in these circumstances.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hiearchy query and cross join as follows:

```
select * from (select rec_id, 
       case lvl when 1 then p_code when 2 then q_code else r_code end as p_code,
       case lvl when 1 then p_amt when 2 then q_amt else r_amt end as p_amount
  from test_tab 
cross join (select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 3) )
where p_code is not null
```

Comment: You might point out that the real work here is done by the cross join, together with the `case` expression. (That was the old way to do unpivoting, before the `unpivot` operator was added in Oracle 11.1.) The hierarchical query is just a convenient way to generate a table with three rows; there are several other ways, and all would work equally well with the cross join idea to generate the unpivoted output.

Comment: Also. you need a `where` clause to discard the rows where the code and the amount are `null`. That is the default in `unpivot`, but the "default" in the cross join approach is the equivalent of the `include nulls` in `unpivot`, and the OP shows that he doesn't want nulls included in the output.

Comment: Ok, Null check was applied in the answer. But it is convenient way, atleast I see it.

Comment: I agree - the "old way" of unpivoting is convenient, especially in other, more complex situations; it is more flexible, there are some things you can do with cross join that you can't do (easily) with the `unpivot` operator. That isn't the case in the problem in this thread, but there are many other problems where knowing the "old way" of unpivoting is very helpful. (Same, by the way, with the "old way" of pivoting, with conditional aggregation.)